# How to switch between grid layout and list layout in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, layout

Using angular 2.0.0 to build an app. I would like to display list of users in two different layout options so that the user can switch between a 'grid layout' which will display the information of users as cards and 'list layout' which would display the information in a tabular format.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Few options I have explored are

- using `*ngFor` to display data as both a `table` and `cards in a
  grid`and using `*ngIf` to display one or the other based on a toggle
  switch.
- using two different templates `<template>` one for the
  `table` layout and another for `cards in a grid` layout and using
  `ViewChild` to render one or the other based on the toggle switch.

Maybe some other way to achieve this?

Comment: would be cool if you achieve that using css classes. Though its timetaking, it reduces code repeatability and app size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have decided to do it using two different templates and the toggle switch. Seems the best solution thus far in latest version of angular.